# Save Ajax POST data to file using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am posting some data to a PHP file using ajax and saving it to a MySQL database. This works fine, but I also want to save one of the data elements to a text file (which should be created) on the server but I can't get it to save to a file.

This is how my code looks:

**jQuery** (snippet)

```
        var uid = "1";
        var name = "bruno";
        var number = "0889-123-123";
        var location = "{"locationInfo":[{"title":"home","lat":-16.450902223672625,"lng":10.6103515625,"speed":""},{"title":"work","lat":-14.94621907436008,"lng":17.99560546875,"speed":""}]}"
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {uid:uid, name:name, number:number, location:location},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        })
```

**PHP - process.php**

```
<?php
    $inputvalues = $_POST;
    $errors = false;
    $result = false;
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', "root", "", "tp");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
            foreach ($inputvalues as $key => $value) {
            if(isset($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $inputvalues[$key] = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $value );
            } else {
                $errors[$key] = 'The field '.$key.' is empty';
            }
        }

        if( !$errors ) {
            $mysqli->query("
                INSERT INTO `table`(`uid`, `name`, `number`) 
                values ('".$inputvalues['uid']."', '".$inputvalues['name']."', '".$inputvalues['number']."');
            ");
            file_put_contents('saved/file.txt', file_get_contents('".$inputvalues['location']."'));
        }
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
        $returnResult ="success";
        echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);
        exit;
?>
```

Comment: I think you are forgetting to mention the problem

Comment: Edited and clarified the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your error log? Is the server able to write to `saved/file.txt`?

Comment: Yes I have! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
file_put_contents('saved/file.txt', file_get_contents('".$inputvalues['location']."'));
```

to this:

```
file_put_contents('saved/file.txt', $inputvalues['location']);
```

Also, in JS you need to remove the quotations from your `location` object.

It should be like this:

```
var location = {"locationInfo": [{"title": "home", "lat": -16.450902223672625, "lng": 10.6103515625, "speed": ""}, {"title": "work", "lat": -14.94621907436008, "lng": 17.99560546875, "speed": ""}]};
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much. It is however adding forward slashes before every quotation mark in my location object like this: `{\"locationInfo\":[{\"title\":\"home\"`

Comment: @Bruno that's because you're calling $mysqli->real_escape_string() on it before saving it into the file.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much obe

Answer (score 0):

@CodeGodie $inputvalues['location'] doesn't seem to contain a file location.

Maybe like this?

```
file_put_contents('saved/file.txt', $inputvalues['location']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input obe